# Context menu doesn't show bound items when opened explicitely (via ContextMenu.IsOpen)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
      <TextBox MouseRightButtonUp="TextBox_OnMouseRightButtonUp">
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"></ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
      </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
namespace ContextMenuIssue
{
    class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
            _items = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
        }

        private List<string> _items;
        public List<string> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new Model();
        }

        private void TextBox_OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //TextBox textBox = ((TextBox) sender);

            //textBox.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            //e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it and right click on the textbox, I get a context menu populated, as expected by 3 items (A, B and C). However, if I try to open the context menu explictely, by commenting out the code in `TextBox_OnMouseRightButtonUp` I get an empty context menu.

When I was trying to debug it, it seems that the context menu object exists, but it is empty and uninitialized, e.g, its ItemsSource property is set to null.

Anyone has an idea why it happens?

Comment: Maybe in the default processing of the right click, WPF assigns the DataContext to the context menu. In my code, when opening manually a conext menu, I do this: this.ContextMenu.DataContext = this.DataContext. And the menu works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContextMenu does not belong to the element tree, and because of this, the DataContext property cannot be propagated to the ContextMenu. To workaround this, manually set the data context for the ContextMenu in your OnMouseRightButtonUp:

textBox.ContextMenu.DataContext = this.DataContext;

Comment: Err. You are right! But I am confused. Why does it work just fine when I'm opening the context menu implicitly? Without the event? Shouldn't it have the same issue with DataContext?

Comment: Hard to tell why it's working, probably, as Jogy mentioned, WPF attached the DataContext to the context menu. A quick test showed that in ContextMenuOpening event the DataContext of the context menu is null but in the ContextMenuOpened event the DataContext is set to your view model (when 'implicitly' open the context menu).